# Assert if any TestStep failed

Tags: groovy, soap, soapui, assert

how can I assert if any of the TestSteps failed using Groovy Script? I have written a groovy script script that among other things run another TestCase and I want it to assert every TestStep (in called TestCase) if it failed. Currently it check TestSteps but it does not include Groovy Script Steps (Groovy Script steps that have asserts inside of them).

This is what I have so far...

```
//Get TestStepList from called Project
def assertFinishedStatus = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).getTestStepList()
//Assert if any step with assertions failed in called TestCase
def moduleStatus = true;
assertFinishedStatus.each{
     // check that testStep has assertionStatus 
    // (for example groovy testSteps hasn't this property since
    // there is no asserts on its)
    if(it.metaClass.hasProperty(it,'assertionStatus')){
        if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.FAILED){
            log.info "TestStep: ${it.name}   - - - - - - - - - - - -   Status: FAILED"
            return moduleStatus = false;
        }else if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.VALID || it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.UNKNOWN){
            log.info "TestStep: ${it.name}   - - - - - - - - - - - -   Status: OK!"
            return moduleStatus = true;
        }
    }
}
assert(moduleStatus != false)
```

UPDATE:
I hope that description below will clarify thing that I want to achieve

I use Z_TC_DodawanieDwochLiczb_exp to run other TestCases (in different projects). Groovy Script EXECUTE does all the work (get properties from one TestCase and sets them in diifferent one, run that other TestCase and so on...). M_TC_Dodwanie is TestCase that I run by that Groovy Script TestStep EXECUTE_Dodawanie, as You can see it failed on AssertResult Groovy Script Step, but didn't fail Z_TC_DodawanieDwochLiczb_exp (which I want it to do if any TestStep in other TestCases like M_TC_Dodawanie failes). And I want it done in EXECUTE_Dodawanie TestStep in Z_TC_DodawanieDwochLiczb_exp.

I know I shouldn't do any dependencies between other TestCases/Projects etc. however I have to, because it's not up to me

[image: Two TestCases and Groovy Script]

Answer (score 0):

Groovy script test steps have assertions within their code, but you can check their **results**:

```
for (r in testRunner.results ) {
  // log.info "TestStep " + r.testStep.name + " status: ${r.getStatus()}"
  assert r.getStatus().toString().equals("OK")
}
```

Checking the results is more reliable, since Groovy script test step and some others do not have assertion properties.

Comment: I think that I cannot use .results on another TestCases that I run by using 

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName(projectName).getTestSuiteByName(testSuitetName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName)

I added a screenshot and update to the question, so maybe it will be more understandable what I want to do